# AS3 Access a method inside the Main class from another class . Gives error?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have trouble with actionScript , im trying to use a simple one line code to access a method inside the Document Class (Main) , but every time i got error . i tried the same code with a movieClip on stage, it work nicely .

***Main Class linked to the fla :***

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;


public class Main extends MovieClip {


    public function Main() {

        if (stage) {
            init();

        }
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


    }
    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,_click);

    }
    private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var l:Leecher = new Leecher();
        l.leech();
    }


    public function callMe():void {
        trace("hey nice work");
    }

}

}
```

***Leecher Class :***

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;

    public class Leecher extends MovieClip {

        public function leech():void
        {
            trace(" leech function ");

            Main(parent).callMe();       // output null object
            Main(root).callMe();        // output null object
            Main(Main).callMe();       // output null object


        }

    }

}
```

***The Same code , but the class linked to a button on stage***

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Button extends MovieClip {


        public function Button() {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,r_click);
        }
        private function r_click(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var l:Leecher = new Leecher();
            l.leech();
            Main(parent).callMe();  // hey nice work
            Main(root).callMe();    // hey nice work
            Main(Main).callMe();    // output null object

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **DisplayObject.parent** and **DisplayObject.root** are defined **ONLY** when the **DisplayObject** in question is attached to stage's display list. The **Button** instance is attached and thus works, the **Leecher** instance is not attached to anything and its **parent** and **root** are both **null**. Then, **Main(anything)** is a type casting and class itself is not an instance, so **Main(Main)** will always give **null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are because when that code runs, the `Leecher` instance has not yet been added to the display list,  and as such does not have a `parent` or `root` or `stage` (so `parent` is `null`).

Here is a breakdown of what's happening (explained with code comments):

```
private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //you instantiate a new Leecher object
    var l:Leecher = new Leecher();

    //you call leech, but this new object does not have a parent because you haven't added it to the display list (via `addChild(l)`)
    l.leech();
}

//your saying parent should be of type Main, then call the callMe method.  However, parent is null because this object is not on the display list
Main(parent).callMe(); 

//same as above, except using root
Main(root).callMe();

//Here you are saying the Main class is of type Main (which since Main is a class and not an instance of Main will error or be null)
Main(Main).callMe();
```

The `root`, `parent` & `stage` vars of a display object are only populated when said display object is added to to the display list.  In the case of `root` & `stage` the parent (and any grand parents) must also be added so that the top most parent/grandparent is the `stage`.

As a result, you need to wait until it's safe to access `parent` by listening for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event.

```
private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var l:Leecher = new Leecher();

    //call the leech method once the child has been added to the stage and has a parent value
    l.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, l.leech, false, 0, true);
    addChild(l);
}
```

If you do the above, you'll need to add an optional event parameter to the leech method or you'll get an error:

```
public function leech(e:Event = null):void
{
```

---

To make your Main class easily accessible, you could use a static reference.
Static vars are not tied to an instance of an object, but to the class itself.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    //create a static var that holds a reference to the root/main instance 
    public static var main:Main;

    public function Main() {
        //assign the static var to this (the instance of Main)
        main = this;

        //...rest of code
```

If you do that, you can asses your root anywhere in your code by doing `Main.main` so in your example you could then do:

```
Main.main.callMe();
```

I'd recommend reading about static vars more before going crazy using them. Doing what I've just shown for an easy reference to your document class / root is safe, but in other contexts there are some memory & performance nuances it's best to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you the : `addChild(l);` fix the error for me , 
best regard